# Mongodb SSL - unable to get issuer certificate

Tags: mongodb, ssl, openssl, lets-encrypt

I am trying to configure ssl/tls with `mongod` on ubuntu 20.04 LTS. mongod version is 5.0.5.
For generating ssl/tls, I am using ssl/ssl certificates from `let's encrypt`. I used this command for generating ssl/tls certificate.

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http -d example.domain.com
```

To configure it with mongod, I did the following steps

- Copied `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` file into a folder.
- Use this command to generate `mongodb.pem` file for mongod.

  `cat privkey.pem fullchain.pem > mongodb.pem`
- For `ca.pem` ,I went to this URL, https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/ and downloaded `Intermediate Certificates -> Active -> Let’s Encrypt R3 -> Signed by ISRG Root X1 (pem)` file. Saved this file with name `ca.pem` in the same directory of `fullchain.pem/privkey.pem` files.
- Verified certificate using this command. It returned `mongodb.pem: OK`

  `openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt mongodb.pem`
- Then I configure ssl/tls configuration with mongod, Added the following lines in `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /path/to/mongodb.pem
    CAFile: /path/to/ca.pem
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: false
```

- Restarted mongod service and It is running with `active (running)` status.
- I am trying to connect to mongodb using the following command.

```
mongo --tls --tlsCAFile ca.pem --tlsCertificateKeyFile mongodb.pem --host mongodb.example-domain.com
```

- But I am getting this error when I try to connect to mongodb using above command,

```
SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get issuer certificate
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong in the whole process. If anybody can help me in this ssl/tls certificate issue. Thanks

Comment: Ensure your Ubuntu OS and mongo installation both trust the Let's Encrypt Intermediate and Root CAs.  Also, ensure the Let's Encrypt Intermediate CA is listed in your mongod server response.  You can check this last piece using `openssl s_client -connect mongodb.example-domain.com:443 -showcerts`  You should see your server cert and the Let's Encrypt Intermdiate CA in the response.